# Объясните пожалуйста как работать правильно с strset

Tags: char, c, строки, c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char *string = "1234";

    printf("do: %s\n", string);
    char* _strset_(char* string, char chr);
    char chr = 'c';
    printf("POSLE: %s", string);
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)int main(), а не void (или "int main(int argc, char *argv[])", если вы хотите передать какие-то параметры вашей программе), и соответственно программа должна возвращать значение типа int при завершении;
2)Присваивать значение переменной chr нужно до того, как с этой переменной ведется какая-то работа, в вашем случае даже если бы strset работала, она заполняла бы строку string неизвестно чем;
3)Насколько я понимаю, strset() принимает вторым параметром аргумент типа int, а не char ([link](http://www.npora.ru/strset.htm));
4)Строка вида "`char *string = "1234";`" - указание компилятору создать указатель на константную! строку, если вы попытаетесь модифицировать данные, на которые он ссылается, получите segmentation fault

К сожалению, у меня в дистрибутивах в библиотеке string.h функции strset() нет, поэтому проверить ее работу я не могу, но если в вашей библиотеке под Visual она есть, то должно работать так :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[10] = "1234";
    int chr = 'c';

    printf("do: %s\n", string);

    strset(string,chr);

    printf("POSLE: %s", string);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Если же данной функции все же нет и в вашей библиотеке, можно заменить ее на собственную :

```
char *my_strset(char* str, int c)
{
        char* ptr = str;
        while(*ptr != '\0'){
            *ptr = (char)c;
            ptr++;
        }
        return str;
}
```